# Pandas Window functions to calculate percentage for groupby

Tags: python, pandas

For each Location and Acquisition channel I would like to calculate the percentage.
For example: The `Digital` acquisition channel in `Milan` makes up 33% of all customers in Milan and 24% of total spend across all acquisition channels in Milan

DF

```
city   acquisition_channel customers  spend
Milan  Digital             23         120
Milan  Organic             35         324
Milan  Email               12         53
Paris  Digital             44         135
Paris  Organic             24         252
Paris  Email               10         47
```

Desired Output DF

```
city   acquisition_channel customers  spend
Milan  Digital             33%         24%
Milan  Organic             50%         65%
Milan  Email               17%         11%
Paris  Digital             56%         31%
Paris  Organic             31%         58%
Paris  Email               13%         11%
```

This is what I have tried so far, but this is not giving me the desired result

```
df.groupby(["acquisition_channel","city"])\
.agg({"customers": "sum", "spend" : "sum"})[["customers", "spend"]]\
.apply(lambda x: 100*x/x.sum())\
.sort_values(by=["customers","spend"], ascending=[False,False])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   df[['customers','spend']]=((
    df.groupby("city")[['customers','spend']].apply(lambda x:((x/x.sum())*100)#Compute percentage
                          .round(0) # Round it to whole number
                          .astype(int)))#Convert to integer
.astype(str)+'%'#Convert to string and append the percentage sign

)



    city acquisition_channel customers spend
0  Milan             Digital       33%   24%
1  Milan             Organic       50%   65%
2  Milan               Email       17%   11%
3  Paris             Digital       56%   31%
4  Paris             Organic       31%   58%
5  Paris               Email       13%   11%
```

Comment: This does not print the city as well as the acquisition channel columns

Comment: That replicates the output you gave I think